# Hide filter depending on sheet in dashboard

Tags: tableau-api

Hope you can help.

I have attached my workbook. Basically, I have made swapping sheets. The sheets have different filters, and I need the filters to disappear depending on the sheet showing.

I have no problem with the sheet swapping. I been going through the internet for hours, without finding a good solution. I did look into this: New series of videos on swapping and popping on a dashboard(https://vimeo.com/294170859), but did not find it that helpful since it is not very flexible and too difficult to use if you have many filters, that need to change.

I have some kind of an Idea, of putting my filters in each of their container, and then have the container showing depending the sheet but do not how either.

But in the end, the filters needs to appear in the same spots too.

But I really need your help - Simply can't find a good solution!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Without putting your filters in containers and swapping those I can't think of any alternative way to alter which filters appear on your dashboard.

I don't know the exact specifics of your task, however, having perhaps faced similar issues almost always the best solution is to simplify. If possible instead of swapping sheets consider a new dashboard and just "show sheets as tabs". Altering a parameter is a click, just as clicking a dashboard tab - so no difference to the user. Also changing filters may be confusing to a user - they generally get used to seeing things in a certain place.

Of course none of this may apply to your specific situation.

Comment: Hi! I ended up shifting between Dashboards. It worked perfectly! :) Thank you